# Как задать цвет графику в Excel из Delphi?

Tags: delphi, excel

Из Delphi запускаю объект Excel 2003 и динамически заполняю шаблон данными. Мне нужно динамически добавить на диаграмму новый график (получилось), и задать ему новый цвет (вопрос про это).

Примерный код - создаем новый график в уже существующей диаграмме:

```
chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries;
chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name := ..
chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values := ..
chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues := ..

chart.SeriesCollection(1). .... Color := RGB(255, 50, 0); // ?
```

Как задать свой RGB цвет этому новому графику?

P.S. Запись макроса, ни в 2003, ни в 2007 Excel, выставление цвета не показывает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался тривиален - цвет задается вот так:

```
chart.SeriesCollection(1).Interior.Color := RGB(255, 50, 0);
```

Единственная проблема в том, что Excel приводит назначаемый цвет к своей палитре. В итоге решение половинчатое, т.к. нельзя задать по-настоящему **свой** цвет.